# HLS fragment length and playlist length with nginx-rtmp module

Tags: nginx, streaming, http-live-streaming

I installed nginx and the nginx-rtmp module on Amazon Linux.
RTMP stream works fine, but some configure about HLS does not work.

On configuration file,

```
rtmp {    
    server {    
        listen 1935;    
        max_streams 32;    
        chunk_size 4096;    

        access_log /var/log/nginx/rtmp_access.log;    
         application live {    
            live on;    
            hls on;    
            hls_path /usr/local/nginx/html/hls;    
            hls_playlist_length 4s;    
            hls_fragment 1s;    
            hls_continuous on;    
        }    
    }
```

but when I start streaming, .m3u8 file is created like this

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:8.333,
test-0.ts
#EXTINF:8.333,
test-1.ts
#EXTINF:8.334,
test-2.ts
```

These .ts file length and playlist length are not expected. Why?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution yet? I'm having the same problem. Btw, what does hls_playlist_lenght do in your config?

Answer (score 3):

It seem likes your video source has a special keyframe, which is minimum at 8s, you can't cut it into 1s segments. And the `hls_playlist_length` must be longer than each segment'length. You should change `hls_playlist_length` to 20s for example.

Comment: For a given mp4 file how can we find its default "special key frame" ?

Comment: @OAH run the following:

`probtime=20 && ffprobe -hide_banner -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -skip_frame nokey -v 0 -read_intervals "%+$probtime" -i INPUT.mp4 | awk -v probtime="$probtime" '{print probtime/$1}'`

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know.